# How to write Json response to a CSV file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to write my JSON response values in CSV in Jmeter,pls help me with the code to extract and write in CSV.

JSON response looks like below-

{"isSuccess":true,"response":{"appDetailsId":8350,"lifeAssuredId":11816,"proposerId":11816,"bitlyLink":"","pQuoteNo":"PA00000232","validationResponse":{"fieldValidationResponse":{"isFieldLevelValidationSuccess":true,"fieldLevelErrorMessage":[]},"businessValidationResponse":{"isBusinessLevelValidationSuccess":true,"businessLevelErrorMessage":[]}}},"errorMessage":null}

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the "values" you want using i.e. [JSON Path Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) or [JSON JMesPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor). If you need help in coming up with correct JsonPath or JMesPath expression - update your question with the values you need to extract.
2. Declare the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) names holding the values using [`sample_variables` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
3. Add [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) to your test plan (install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) if it's not there yet)
4. Configure Flexible File Writer to store the values into the file of your choice.